# Angular Material - disable theme but use it only for spinner?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am using Angular Material for Angular 1.*. I have themeing disabled with `$mdThemingProvider.disableTheming();`. However, I would like to use the progress spinner and it is broken without using Angular's default theme. Is there a way I could have the themeing disabled but have the default theme only applied to the spinner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with CSS - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/vyLGXg)

Markup

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp">
  <md-button class="md-primary">Hello</md-button>
  <md-progress-circular md-mode="indeterminate"></md-progress-circular>
</div>
```

CSS

```
md-progress-circular path {
  stroke: rgb(63, 81, 181);
}
```

JS

```
angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial'])

.config(function ($mdThemingProvider) {
  $mdThemingProvider.disableTheming();
})

.controller('AppCtrl', function() {
});
```